# Accessing variables declared within onCreateView() from class methods

Tags: java, variables, scope

If I have variables that are declared within the onCreateView of a fragment; is there a way I can access those variables from outside the onCreateView?

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {
        superContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        digitalfragmentview = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);

        digitalIO0Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio0mode);
        digitalIO1Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio1mode);
        digitalIO2Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio2mode);
        digitalIO3Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio3mode);
        digitalIO4Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio4mode);
        digitalIO5Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio5mode);
        digitalIO6Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio6mode);
        digitalIO7Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio7mode);
        digitalIO8Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio8mode);
        digitalIO9Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio9mode);


        centralDigitalTable = (TableLayout) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalTable);

        Switch[] digitalIOModeSwitchArray = {digitalIO0Mode, digitalIO1Mode,
                digitalIO2Mode, digitalIO3Mode, digitalIO4Mode, digitalIO5Mode,
                digitalIO6Mode, digitalIO7Mode, digitalIO8Mode, digitalIO9Mode};


        return digitalfragmentview;
    }
```

Now I have these methods within the class:

```
   public Switch getIOModeSwitch(int index) {
        return digitalIOModeSwitchArray[index];
    }

    public void getIOModeSwitch(int index, boolean status) {
        digitalIOModeSwitchArray[index].setActivated(status);
    }
```

However; they obviously cannot access digitalIOModeSwitchArray as it is out of their scope and localized to the onCreateView method.

**I tried to put all of the initiation of the variables after the class's header however the arrays seem to fill with null if I do it that way so I apparently cannot do it that way.**

**EDIT 1:**

For instance,

if I did this -

```
public class digitalFragment extends FragmentActivity{
digitalIO0Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio0mode);
        digitalIO1Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio1mode);
        digitalIO2Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio2mode);
        digitalIO3Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio3mode);
        digitalIO4Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio4mode);
        digitalIO5Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio5mode);
        digitalIO6Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio6mode);
        digitalIO7Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio7mode);
        digitalIO8Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio8mode);
        digitalIO9Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                .findViewById(R.id.digitalio9mode);
Switch[] digitalIOModeSwitchArray = {digitalIO0Mode, digitalIO1Mode,
                digitalIO2Mode, digitalIO3Mode, digitalIO4Mode, digitalIO5Mode,
                digitalIO6Mode, digitalIO7Mode, digitalIO8Mode, digitalIO9Mode};


    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater viewInflation, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle SavedInstantState) {
        superContext = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        digitalfragmentview = viewInflation.inflate(
                R.layout.digitalfragment_page, container, false);



        // sets the listener for the mode switches
        for (int i = 0; i < digitalIOModeSwitchArray.length; i++) {
            if (digitalIOModeSwitchArray[i] == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Array is null at:" + i);
            }
        }

        return digitalfragmentview;
    }
```

}

the logcat output looks like:

```
Array is null at: 1
Array is null at: 2
Array is null at: 3
Array is null at: 4
Array is null at: 5
Array is null at: 6
Array is null at: 7
Array is null at: 8
Array is null at: 9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot access local variables from outside the scope they were declared in.

You would have to declare them as member fields in the class. Check out the official tutorial on [Member Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html).

```
class Example {

    int field;
    int hello = 2; // initialized to 2
    int there;
    Object[] array = new Object[50]; // array initialized here, all elements null

    Example () {
       there = 2; // can also be initialized in constructor
       // initialize each element of array:
       for (int n = 0; n < array.length; ++ n)
           array[n] = new Object();
    }

    void a () {
       int local;
       local = 1; // ok
       field = 1; // ok
       hello = 1; // ok
       there = 1; // ok
    }

    void b () {
       System.out.println(local); // no 'local' declared here
       System.out.println(field); // ok
       System.out.println(hello); // ok
       System.out.println(there); // ok
    }

}
```

Edit: Expanded example re: comments and edit to post.

Comment: However; if I declare them as fields (I.E. just copying and pasting them from the onCreateView();) they instantiate as null when I do a log output  check on the array?

Comment: Typical practice is create them as a field, but instantiate (give them a value, so they're non-null) them in `onCreateView` (or in the constructor if it's not specifically an Android `Activity`).

Comment: @Tukajo Yes, fields are initialized to `null`. You can initialize them when they are declared, or in the constructor, though, if you want them to never be `null`. You can also declare them as `final` if they shouldn't be modified. You can also initialize them on first use (`if (x == null) x = new Whatever()`).

Comment: @EmbattledSwag I tried that before; and they still instantiated to null after I create them as fields and initiated them in onCreateView.

Comment: @Tukajo If you create a new array of objects its values will be null. You would have to loop through the array and instantiate each element if you want that to not be the case. See updated example.

Comment: Sorry to be a bother; but given my example code; how would I instantiate and initiate each value of my array digitalIOModeSwitchArray[i] for each variable digitalIO0Mode, digitalIO1Mode, etc etc... dynamically. Basically is there a way to search and add variables via a string?

Comment: @Tukajo Either a) declare your array as a field, initialized to `new Switch[whateverFixedSize]` and just assign `digitalIOModeSwitchArray[0] = ...`, `digitalIOModeSwitchArray[1] = ...` in `onCreateView`, or b) consider using a dynamic array like [`ArrayList<Switch>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), which you can `add()` to as needed.

Comment: Gotcha; I guess that is a valid way of doing it I was just wondering if there was a better-practice to use in terms of assigning variables to array indices.

Comment: @Tukajo The best practice is to clearly define your requirements, then decide what you need to do to implement that, then implement it. To give better advice on those lines, you have to consider more than the  info you gave us, e.g. how are these values used, when are these values used, do they change, what assumptions can other bits of code make about them, etc. Consider all that when deciding (e.g. perhaps a `Map<Integer,Switch>` that maps IDs to `Switch` is more appropriate, etc.). As for just assigning variables: Assign a value to a variable when you want it to have a [new] value! :)

Comment: (BTW, declaring `int[] x` then later doing `x = new int[anySize]` is valid too, if you'd like to allocate a fixed-size array at a size that isn't known until you're ready to populate it.

Answer (score 1):

As per your edit, you're trying to initialize your varaibles (`digitalIO1Mode`, etc.) to `View`s before the `Activity` is even aware of them, thus they're all null.

Try just putting `Switch digitalIO1Mode;`,`Switch digitalIO2Mode;`, etc. before your `onCreate` and then, after you call `setContenView`, THATS when you set them equal to the `View`s.

Answer (score 1):

Just going to explain why this doesn't work for the OP

```
public class digitalFragment extends FragmentActivity{

digitalIO0Mode = (Switch) digitalfragmentview
                 .findViewById(R.id.digitalio0mode);
```

You haven't inflated a view into digitalfragmentview yet, so it cannot find R.id.digitalio0mode.   I'm surprised you actually didn't crash here with a NullPointerException since digitalfragmentview should probably be null here, but I don't see your declaration statement for that view, so it's plausible you had some other view loaded into it.

```
Switch[] digitalIOModeSwitchArray = {digitalIO0Mode, digitalIO1Mode,
            digitalIO2Mode, digitalIO3Mode, digitalIO4Mode, digitalIO5Mode,
            digitalIO6Mode, digitalIO7Mode, digitalIO8Mode, digitalIO9Mode};
```

This doesn't work, because as we said above, the switches aren't findable until you inflate the view, so at best you're just placing nulls here.

The way you do it is simply declare the definition of switch as a field.

```
Switch[] digitalIOModeSwitchArray;
```

and then in your on create, just keep the same code you have in your original post, except don't define a local Switch[] digitalIOModeSwitchArray, refer to your global one so it points to a value.